# magento 2, is it possible in custom theme set 1-column layout for category list page if it's first level category

Tags: magento2, category, layout, sidebar

Wondering how to remove sidebar from topl level category list page that parent is `Default Category` through code not admin panel? Considering after setting template categories are going to be created, so no info about their ids.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate xml file for all of your top level category by below way.

```
catalog_category_view_id_{idnumber}
```

If your category with id is 3 then **catalog_category_view_id_3** and keep this file inside your module or theme level.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I was aware about this solution. But how bout if later customer add new main category? Is there any more general way? thanks (I edited my question to address this specification)